# Socket.io - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I wrote this:

```js
io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit() // I'm sure `socketId` exists and connected.
```

But an error occurs:

```
(node:2416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at ~/transmister/transmister-server-and-web/server.js:71:60
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:2416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 5)
```

My Socket.io version is `"socket.io": "^2.3.0"`.

Is this API deprecated? Or something wrong with my code?

Comment: `socketId` might exist but `io.sockets.connected[socketId]` does not.

Comment: I think the best way is to store any socket on `connect` event and remove it on `disconnect`. Btw does `io.sockets.sockets[socketId]` works ?

Comment: @Namysh [MrWillCom/labs/tree/master/socket.io-specific-msgs](https://github.com/MrWillCom/labs/tree/master/socket.io-specific-msgs) , I've tested recently.

Comment: Instead of : 
`sockets.push(socket.id)` then `io.sockets.connected[socket.id].emit('event', 'message');`

, try `sockets[socket.id] = socket;` then `sockets[socket.id].emit('event', 'message');`

Comment: @Namysh that demo is the way I realize it, It works, but it doesn't work [here](https://github.com/transmister/transmister-server-and-web), could you help me find the problem? Here is [README](https://github.com/transmister/work-share/blob/master/transmister-server-and-web/quick-start.md).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it's something wrong with my database, not socket.io. It's fixed now.